# jQuery smooth scrolling to anchor not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used smooth scrolling before with no issues as I am unsure what is preventing it working this time. I am not getting any errors in the console that has anything to do with the smooth scrolling. The website url is:

http://tinyurl.com/oprfwd6

And the current code for smooth scrolling:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($){ 
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
  var target = $(this.hash);
  target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
  if (target.length) {
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
    return false;
  }
}
});
});
```

If any one has any suggestions as to what could be preventing that would be great.

Comment: i see at least one error in the console 'showLeft is not defined'. I suggest fixing it and see if it helps.

Comment: @yuyokk I have fixed that error, any other thoughts? Thanks - Ben